# Reversing xticklabels in MATLAB 2014B

Tags: matlab, plot

I am running Matlab 2014b and am trying to define my `xticklabels` but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
x = 0:1000:10000;
y = rand(1,11);
plot(x,y)
xlim([0 10000])
ax.XTick = [0 2000 4000 6000 8000 10000];
ax.XTickLabel = {'10000', '8000', '6000', '4000', '2000', '0'};
xlabel('Years Before Present','fontsize',8)
```

I would like the `xticklabels` to be in reverse (without changing the plot as it is in years before present). Where am I going wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the current axes there with `ax` and then later on in the codes after initializing `ax.XTickLabel`, flip/reverse the tick-labels with `ax.XTickLabel = flip(ax.XTickLabel)` or `ax.XTickLabel = ax.XTickLabel(end:-1:1)`.

Here's the code to compare the *before* and *after* effect of the original and the proposed approach as fully runnable codes -

```
x = 0:1000:10000; %// Inputs
y = rand(1,11);

figure,
plot(x,y)
ax = gca;
xlim([0 10000])
ax.XTick = [0 2000 4000 6000 8000 10000];
ax.XTickLabel = {'10000', '8000', '6000', '4000', '2000', '0'};
xlabel('Years Before Present','fontsize',8), title('BEFORE')

figure,
plot(x,y)
ax = gca;                                %// get current axes [CHANGE-1]
xlim([0 10000])
ax.XTick = [0 2000 4000 6000 8000 10000];
ax.XTickLabel = {'10000', '8000', '6000', '4000', '2000', '0'};
ax.XTickLabel = ax.XTickLabel(end:-1:1)  %// flip ticklabels [CHANGE-2]
xlabel('Years Before Present','fontsize',8), title('AFTER')
```

Outputs -

[image]

[image]